# PHP MySQL image does not insert to database, even when echo works phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

If I try to submit an image, the echo works. So i'll see "it works". But when I check my db, it is not inserted. 
userId is a INT and foreign key to the id in another table and image is a BLOB.

code:

```
$userId = $_SESSION['id'];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


        $imgName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $imgData = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $getImgData = file_get_contents($imgData);
        $imgType = $_FILES['image']['type'];

        if(substr($imgType, 0,5) == "image"){
            $query = "INSERT INTO projects (userId, image)
                      VALUES ('$userId', '$getImgData')";

            $result = $db->query($query);


            echo "it works!";

        } else{
            echo "only images are allowed";
        }

}

?>
```

The echo works, but it won't insert. Please help with this, I've been stuck for hours now!

Comment: `won't insert` is not sufficient to explain **how** it doesn't work. Always check for query success after performing one, databases will happily report why something doesn't work. Just use the tools you have at your disposal.

Comment: it works fine in phpmyadmin, so it has to do something about my code..

Comment: So what part of my comment was unclear? You won't check for query success status and print errors if status is false?

Comment: the query is fine, i have checked it, and it inserts everyrhing fine. the only time when it's not working is when i try to insert an image. sorry to bother im just not that good with php

Answer (score 1):

why insert the image in the db, just get the img path (upload folder) or name and insert it, in your code you can show your image by referencing it's path, except if you must insert it as blob you can refer to this posts

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-mysql-blob/

Comment: but will this also work if another user tries to submit an image? the registered user has to be able to change it's profile photo

Comment: if a user want to change his profile photo you need to override the img path in the db and remove the old picture from the upload folder use unlink() function to do that